# Mysql update error

Tags: mysql

i've get this error:
Unknown column 'richard' in 'where clause'
in this code :

```
if(isset($_POST['Zabanovat'])){;
    $nick = $_POST['nick'];
    $ban = $_POST['ban'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE TABLE Set usr_unban = $ban   WHERE usr_nick =  $nick    ") OR die(mysql_error());
}

echo "<form method=\"post\">";

echo "<div class=\"formatLabel\"><label for=\"nick\"><h2>Zadejte jméno banovaného účtu</h2></label></div>";
echo "<div class=\"formatContent\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"nick\" name=\"nick\"></div>";

    echo "<div class=\"formatLabel\"><label for=\"ban\"><h2>Zadejte datum unbanu (dd.mm.yyyy)</h2></label></div>";
echo "<div class=\"formatContent\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"ban\" name=\"ban\"></div>";

echo "<div class=\"formatSubmit\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Zabanovat\" name=\"Zabanovat\"></div>";

echo "</form>";
```

Comment: yikes. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to put variables within single quotes if they don't contain numeric values.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE TABLE Set usr_unban = '$ban' WHERE usr_nick = '$nick'") OR die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the table name when typing the query, unless your table is named "TABLE":

```
mysql_query("UPDATE TABLE Set usr_unban = $ban WHERE usr_nick = $nick ") OR die(mysql_error()); }
```

should be:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE **TABLE_NAME** Set usr_unban = $ban WHERE usr_nick = $nick ") OR die(mysql_error()); }
```

remember, the UPDATE clase in SQL is:

```
UPDATE "table_name"
SET "column_1" = [new value]
WHERE {condition}
```